# 100% RAM usage in google colab when implementing random oversampling and undersampling

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

How can I prevent Google Colab from crashing when using random oversampling and undersampling to address the class imbalance problem in the ISIC-2019 dataset?

I am using the Google Colab Pro version, which provides 83.5 GB of RAM. I have implemented random oversampling and undersampling using imblearn library on the training dataset which contains 17k images. However, while running the code, the RAM usage exceeds the available memory leading to a crash. Is there an alternative method to handle the class imbalance problem without causing the memory overflow issue? Here is the code I am using for reference:

```
import torch
import torch.utils.data as data
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler


train_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(224, interpolation=transforms.InterpolationMode.BICUBIC),
    transforms.RandomCrop(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], 
                         std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
])

train_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root='data/isic2019/ISIC - 2019/train', transform=train_transforms)
test_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root='data/isic2019/ISIC - 2019/test', transform=train_transforms)
val_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root='data/isic2019/ISIC - 2019/val', transform=train_transforms)

# Extract the data and labels from the datasets
train_data = [np.array(sample) for sample, _ in train_dataset]
train_labels = [label for _, label in train_dataset]

# Resample the training data using random oversampling
ros = RandomOverSampler(random_state=42)
train_data_resampled, train_labels_resampled = ros.fit_resample(np.array(train_data).reshape(-1, 224 * 224 * 3), np.array(train_labels))

# Undersample the resampled training data using random undersampling
rus = RandomUnderSampler(random_state=42)
train_data_resampled, train_labels_resampled = rus.fit_resample(train_data_resampled, train_labels_resampled)

# Convert the resampled data back to PIL.Image objects and create a new dataset and dataloader
train_data_resampled = [train_data_resampled[i].reshape(3, 224, 224) for i in range(len(train_data_resampled))]
train_dataset_resampled = data.TensorDataset(torch.stack([torch.from_numpy(sample) for sample in train_data_resampled]), torch.from_numpy(train_labels_resampled))

# Create the test and train dataloader
test_dataloader = data.DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=False)
train_dataloader = data.DataLoader(train_dataset_resampled, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
val_dataloader = data.DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=False)
```

Comment: Why are you converting your data to np.array? I think you need to keep it all in torch and use torch for the resampling and reshaping.

Comment: I've kept everything into torch and used torch for resampling and reshaping but it still crashed unfortunately

Comment: Can you make the data loader do the resampling? It sounds like your dataset is too large to fit in memory. If you must resample it, you would want to load some portion of the data, resample that, and then train with that, before moving on to the next data chunk. It's the same way you copy/stream files without putting the whole file into RAM.